# jQuery :odd or :even to addClass up to a certain selector?

Tags: jquery, addclass

I need to add an alt class (on odd or even) to a selector, and then start fresh again after it reaches another selector.

**What I have**

```
<div class="person"></div>
<div class="person"></div>
<div class="person"></div>
<div class="person"></div>
<div class="person"></div>
<div class="section-separator"></div>
<div class="person"></div>
<div class="person"></div>
```

**What I need**

```
<div class="person"></div>
<div class="person alt"></div>
<div class="person"></div>
<div class="person alt"></div>
<div class="person"></div>
<div class="section-separator"></div>
<div class="person"></div>
<div class="person alt"></div>
```

The issue I run into is it wants to keep counting odd/even from the previous section and not start over again, so my styles do no apply correctly. My current jQuery is `$('.personbox:odd').addClass('alt');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a clever way to do this. The un-clever way is just select the `.person` and `.section-separator` elements and loop through, keeping track of an index:

```js
var index = 0;
$(".person, .section-separator").each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  if ($this.hasClass("section-separator")) {
    index = 0;
  } else {
    if (index % 2 == 1) {
      $this.addClass("alt");
    }
    ++index;
  }
});
```

```css
.alt {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="person">testing</div>
<div class="person">testing</div>
<div class="person">testing</div>
<div class="person">testing</div>
<div class="person">testing</div>
<div class="section-separator">separator</div>
<div class="person">testing</div>
<div class="person">testing</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I was hoping for a "clever" way, but had a feeling I'd need something like this.

Works great.

Comment: I actually had to make a slight change to your answer because I realized it might not always be the section-separator that defines when it needs to reset index w/in our CMS.  So the following works for us...

if (!$this.next().hasClass("personbox"))